# .all() on a Series is returning values from the Series, not True/False

Tags: pandas, series, any

I have a Pandas Series that should be filled with all strings, but I want to make sure there are no missing values.  I thought that `.all()` would do the trick since empty strings are Falsey (right?), but instead, `.all()` (and `.any()`) are returning values from the Series, not `True` or `False` as I expected.

For example:

```
series_1 = pd.Series(['beads', 'doubloons', 'king cake'])
series_2 = pd.Series(['beads', 'doubloons', np.nan, 'king cake'])
series_3 = pd.Series(['beads', '', 'doubloons', np.nan, 'king cake'])
```

I would expect `series_x.any()` or `series_x.all()` to return `True` or `False`, but instead, what is happening is

- `series_1.any()`, `series_2.any()`, and `series_3.any()` each return `'beads'`
- `series_1.all()` and `series_2.all()` return `'king cake'` and `series_3.all()` returns `''`

I am utterly befuddled, and frankly, the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) is no help at all.

Thanks!

Edit: I am running pandas version 1.0.3

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12863

Comment: Oh, ha.  Thanks @Emma.  At least it's not my fault.  If you want to put that in an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @BigBen, pandas 1.0.3.... adding to post now.

Comment: ... time to upgrade :-)